# Kendo Multiselect not showing the previously selected items

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to populate kendo multiselect control. The data does bind to the control and I can see all the currencies from the currencies object but it inst showing the previously selected currencies that is in the ngmodel. How do I show the selected currencies ?

```
                    <kendo-multiselect [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies" style="height: 29.5px;"
                            [(ngModel)]="f.OtherCurrencyName" [textField]="'Name'" [valueField]="'Id'"
                            [autoClose]="false">
                            <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.Name)">
                                <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.Name }}</label>
                            </ng-template>
                    </kendo-multiselect>
```

Component

```
public value: any = [{ Id: null, Name: "" }];

public isItemSelected(itemText: string): boolean {
    return this.value.some(item => item.Name === itemText);
}
```

Currencies object

```
 "Currencies": [
            {
                "Id": 7,
                "Name": "AUD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 10,
                "Name": "BND"
            },
            {
                "Id": 19,
                "Name": "BRL"
            },
            {
                "Id": 6,
                "Name": "CAD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "Name": "CHF"
            },
            {
                "Id": 13,
                "Name": "CNH"
            },
            {
                "Id": 12,
                "Name": "CNY"
            },
            {
                "Id": 18,
                "Name": "DKK"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "EUR"
            }]
```

NgModel

The f.OtherCurrencyName that is assinged to the ngModel contains a string value of 10,19,7 which is comma seperated.

Edit 1

Screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFhqx.png)

Code

```
 <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Id] && c == 'Other Currencies'"
                                    class="tableItem">

                                    <!-- f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyName -->
                                    <kendo-multiselect [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies" style="height: 29.5px;"
                                        [(ngModel)]="f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyName"
                                        [textField]="'Name'" [valueField]="'Id'" [autoClose]="false">
                                        <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"
                                                [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.Name)">
                                            <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.Name }}</label>
                                        </ng-template>
                                    </kendo-multiselect>

                                </td>




public value: any = [];

public valueChange(value: any): void {
   // this.OtherCurrencyName = value.map(x => x.Id).join();
  }

public isItemSelected(itemName: string): boolean {
    return this.value.some(item => item.Name === itemName);
  }
```

OtherCurrencyName

```
 "LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel": {
                    "Description": "Class A",
                    "AuditSummary": "rmenon Jun 10, 2019",
                    "FeesReviewSummary": "dmukerji May 28, 2019",
                    "TermsReviewSummary": "kweigand Jan 16, 2019",
                    "Id": 13713,
                    "FundId": 237146,
                    "FundClassType": 3,
                    "CurrencyId": 19,
                    "PrimaryCurrencyName": "BRL",
                    "OtherCurrencyName": [
                        10,
                        19,
                        7
                    ]
}
```

Currencies object

```
 "Currencies": [
            {
                "Id": 7,
                "Name": "AUD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 10,
                "Name": "BND"
            },
            {
                "Id": 19,
                "Name": "BRL"
            },
            {
                "Id": 6,
                "Name": "CAD"
            }]
```

Comment: Can you please update debuggable version of your code like jsfiddle?

Comment: I have posted the contents of f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyName

Comment: What I have noticed is that you are doing this.value.some(item => item.Name === itemName); and binding value to ngModel. In my case it is f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyName

Comment: Any idea on how I need to get it work in my case. Value property in component has no link with f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyName

Comment: Selected values `[10,19,7]` and options `[{name: "AUD", Id: 1}, { name: "BRL", Id: 2 }]` are not similar array, you have to use array of same format.

Comment: Yes, I had changed that array format to be of the format Id, Name. Initially I had a problem of only numbers showing up the first time if values existed and not their names. Now after changing to the format Id, Name , the name appears on the first load.

Comment: The main issue I am having now is when selecting the items in the list, the row shows highlighted and it does get add to multiselect control but the checkbox doesn't show ticked.Currently I have commented the code in the value change event. The issue that I am having is my ngModel is bound to an array coming from the server and not hardcoded in the component code [(ngModel)]="f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyIds" . How do I write the logic in the isItemSelected event. The value property that you are using is bound to ngModel and you have hardcoded its values in the component

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use this code :

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
  <kendo-multiselect
    [data]="listItems"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [textField]="'name'"
    [valueField]="'Id'"
    [autoClose]="false"
  >
  <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox"
      [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.name)">
    <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.name }}</label>
  </ng-template>
  </kendo-multiselect>
</div>
```

and for ts file :

```
class AppComponent {
   public listItems: Array<{ name: string, Id: number }> = [
      { name: "AUD", Id: 1 },
      { name: "BRL", Id: 2 },        
      { name: "BND", Id: 3 },
      { name: "DKK", Id: 4 },
      { name: "EUR", Id: 5 }
   ];        
   public value: any = [{ name: "BRL", Id: 2 }];

   public isItemSelected(itemName: string): boolean {
      return this.value.some(item => item.name === itemName);
   }
 }
```

Comment: When I try this I can see BRL item in the multiselect already selected but when I try to select the other items the checkbox item doesnt get ticked. I can see only the rows highlighted

Comment: this code is perfectly fine I have checked it, I think you have maybe css conflict or smth like that.

Comment: The issue that I am having is my ngModel is bound to an array coming from the server and not hardcoded in the component code  [(ngModel)]="f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.OtherCurrencyIds" . How do I write the logic in the isItemSelected event. The value property that you are using is bound to ngModel and you have hardcoded its values in the component

Comment: What is f then?

Comment: It refers to LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel which is part of the AllTerms object. *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.AllTerms;